# VolatileImage JFrame on multiple screens

Tags: java, swing, graphics, awt, graphics2d

I have a JFrame in which I am using Graphics2D to draw a VolatileImage using [this](http://www.gpwiki.org/index.php/Java:Tutorials:VolatileImage) tutorial. I have mainly copied the code to see how it works, but have slightly edited it for my game. I am running my computer with two screens.

The problem arises when I drag the window of the game onto the other screen which the window did not originally appear on. The window goes grey and no graphics are shown on screen, even the simple rectangles I have drawn with the Graphics2D. This only happens when I call for the draw method of the volatileimage as shown in the tutorial.

I believe it may have something to do with this...

```
GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
GraphicsConfiguration gc = ge.getDefaultScreenDevice().getDefaultConfiguration();
```

...but I am not sure.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. It would also be interesting to know if VolatileImage is the way I should be going for my game or if BufferedImage or something else is a better method for performance and frame rate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you are correct. `VolatileImage` is device-specific. From ["The VolatileImage API User Guide"](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4/pdf/VolatileImage.pdf) you can read:

> A VolatileImage is device-specific: if you created a VolatileImage with one
>   GraphicsDevice, you might not be able to copy that VolatileImage to another
>   GraphicsDevice. For this reason, you need to call validate before attempting to copy the
>   VolatileImage.

and

> If the code is `IMAGE_INCOMPATIBLE` then the `VolatileImage` is not
>   compatible with the current `GraphicsConfiguration`. This
>   incompatibility can occur if the image was created with one
>   `GraphicsConfiguration` and then drawn into another. **For example,
>   in a multiple-monitor situation, the `VolatileImage` exists is
>   associated with a particular `GraphicsConfiguration`. Copying that
>   image onto a different `GraphicsConfiguration` could cause
>   unpredictable results.** To correct this problem, you need to create a
>   new `VolatileImage` that is compatible with the current
>   `GraphicsConfiguration`

When dragging your frame to another screen device you need to check the result from the [`VolatileImage.validate(gc)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/image/VolatileImage.html#validate%28java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration%29) method of your and recreate the image to the new device. Note that there are cases when you cannot create a `VolatileImage`, in those cases you need to fall back on another `Image` implementation like `BufferedImage`.

Comment: Is VolatileImage worth the fuss then over BufferedImage? :)

Comment: @Humphrey: They are much faster. But in your case it might be a premature optimization, I would recommend to try `BufferedImage` first. :)